# Model key is set to null when EntityState is set to Modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an issue when updating an entity on my dbContext.
The model key is set to null when EntityState is changed to Modified.

```
// myModel.id == 8
var entry = db.Entry(myModel);
// myModel.id == 8
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
// myModel.id == null ????? Why?
```

I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated, Tks.

Comment: Did you load `myModel` from the Context first (using `Find()` or something like that) or did you set `Id = 8` yourself?

Comment: Tanks Marcos, for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where `myModel` has been loaded ? If `myModel` has been loaded from context then dont attach it or else if it has been created outside of context then below code should work :

```
context.MyModels.Attach(myModel); // You should use entity of myModel 
var entry = context.Entry(myModel);
// Do what you want
```

Comment: Tanks Nikunj, you pointed me in the right direction. After reading your awnser I started looking at the problem from a different angle and was able to solve the issue. So I marked your awnser as correct.

Comment: @RUCA, Glad to know that !!